# Multiple Variables / files from resource Android

Tags: android, variables, android-resources, xmlpullparser, android-xmlpullparser

I have 5 files (test1,test2,test3,test4,test5) in Android resources. All resources should be assign to variable **parser**. How it should be done properly?

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.test1);
        databaseHelper myDbHelper  = new databaseHelper(this);

    try {
        //myDbHelper = new databaseHelper(this);


        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();
            if (name.equals("test") || name.equals("test")) {
                String id = null, gname = null, pob = null, pob1 = null, memb = null, seq = null, site = null;
                while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    name = parser.getName();                            
                    if (name.equals("test")) {
                        id = readText(parser);
                    } else if (name.equals("test")) {
```

Comment: Parser variable should use 5 files to parse all resources. Any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723885/variable-in-loop-java

Comment: Here is solution what I need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723885/variable-in-loop-java