# Variable in Loop Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have code:

```
XmlResourceParser parser = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.test1);
```

How to change last object in loop? (object = R.xml.test1)

For example, I create table:

```
int[] table = {(R.xml.test1), (R.xml.test2), (R.xml.test2)}
```

and this my object to change. How can do it properly?

Comment: Not clear. Please explain.

Comment: He wants to use the table array object to change the argument he is passing to `getXml`. He wants to use a loop to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps loop over your table?

```
for (int resource : table) {
    XmlResourceParser parser = context.getResources().getXml(resource);
    //Do whatever you need to do with the parser
}
```